# Flutter Build error=> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildStagingDebug'

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use my physical device for a flutter application, I am doing this through visual studio code.

```
flutter run --flavor=staging
```

OP: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Anand\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildStagingDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Anand\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
  insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleStagingDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleStagingDebug'... Done                134.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleStagingDebug failed with exit code 1`

What should be done in this case?
Thanks

Comment: do you have accept android licences?

Comment: Can you specify how to check that?

Comment: run `flutter doctor` command on your terminal or cmd and post the result